# How to Get Only the Text inside the Brackets [{}]?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`const data = { user: [ { name: 'jack' } ] }`

How do I get only **Jack** when I call the constant.

Comment: `data.user[0].name`

Comment: If *user* is singular the Array `[]` is redundant. I'd rather improve the data response first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saved as an array.
To use its components, you must do the following:

```
data.user[0].name;
data.user[1].name;
data.user[1].age;
```

If you want foreach loop  in JS you can do like this :
@EDIT 1 updated without this

```
const data = [{name:"Jack", age:"50"},{name:"Brook", age:"20"},{name:"Noob", age:"34"}];
for(const n of data) {
   console.log(n.name)
    console.log(n.age)
}
```

@EDIT2

```
const data =  {user : [{name:"Jack", age:"50"},{name:"Brook", age:"20"},{name:"Noob", age:"34"}]};
for(const n of data.user) {
    console.log(n.name)
    console.log(n.age)
}
```

Comment: It works but I have another name also like ```const data = { user: [ { name: 'jack' }, {name: 'brook', age: 20 ] }``` how do I get both names

Comment: Edited , check it. And approve answear if works :)

Comment: I have like more than 100 users and name so I can't use this method

Comment: Edited answear , check it and approve if works :) It will do the same wthing for each user.

Comment: I'm getting an error  ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.data is not iterable```

Comment: OK , sorry my bad - there you need to delete this before data. Updated again JS file , check now

Comment: sorry about this but, I have user inside const, which I can't remove so I have to find a way using user inside const data like ```const data ={user[{name:"Jack", age:"50"},{name:"Brook", age:"20"}]}```

Comment: added @EDIT2 check now.